# How can I create a login page in Symfony 4 without the error "InvalidConfigurationException"?

Tags: php, symfony, security, authentication, error-handling

config/packages/security.yaml:

```
security:
  encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
      algorithm: bcrypt

      # ...

      providers:
        our_db_provider:
          entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: username
            # if you're using multiple entity managers
            # manager_name: customer

            firewalls:
              main:
                anonymous: ~
                form_login:
                  login_path: login
                  check_path: login

                  # ...
                  access_control:
                    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
                    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

src/Controller/SecurityController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
  /**
  * @Route("/login", name="login")
  */
  public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
  {
      // get the login error if there is one
      $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

      // last username entered by the user
      $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

      return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', array(
          'last_username' => $lastUsername,
          'error'         => $error,
      ));
  }
}
```

src/Controller/DefaultController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin")
     */
    public function admin()
    {
        return new Response('<html><body>Admin page!</body></html>');
    }
}
```

templates/security/login.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

    {#
        If you want to control the URL the user
        is redirected to on success (more details below)
        <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
    #}

    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

I want to load my /admin or /login page I get the error:

> InvalidConfigurationException Unrecognized option "providers" under
>   "security.encoders.App\Entity\User"
>
> at ArrayNode->normalizeValue(array('providers' =>
>   array('our_db_provider' => array('entity' => array('class' =>
>   'App\Entity\User', 'property' => 'email', 'firewalls' =>
>   array('main' => array('anonymous' => null, 'form_login' =>
>   array('login_path' => 'login', 'check_path' => 'login',
>   'access_control' => array(array('path' => '^/login', 'roles' =>
>   'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'), array('path' => '^/', 'roles' =>
>   'ROLE_ADMIN'))))))))))in BaseNode.php line 368

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tabulation is wrong in your **security.yaml** configuration.  You have this:

```
security:
  encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
      algorithm: bcrypt

      # ...

      providers:
```

It should instead be:

```
security:
  encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
      algorithm: bcrypt

      # ...

  providers:
```

The `encoders` and `providers` should both 1st-level children under the `security` configuration.

Comment: Thank you, this was solving most errors. But there is still this error: `Cannot determine controller argument for "App\Controller\SecurityController::login()": the $request argument is type-hinted with the non-existent class or interface: "App\Controller\Request". Did you forget to add a use statement?`

Comment: Add `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;` to the top of your `SecurityController` class

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I did it, but still the same error

Comment: Oops I meant `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;`

Comment: Ok, wow! This error is now gone, thank you! But now it is again replaced by a new error :(((( `A template that extends another one cannot include content outside Twig blocks. Did you forget to put the content inside a {% block %} tag?` and the point out this line `<div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>`

Comment: I am sorry :( :(

Comment: Ok, I could solve this one by removing `{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}` Now it is working

Comment: It is also possible to exchange `{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}` with `{% include 'base.html.twig' %}`

Comment: Glad you got that working. I highly suggest reading through more of the Symfony documentation as well as PHP and namespaces. They will help you intuitively solve some of these errors in the future

Comment: Yes, I am working the documentation right now through, I created this login by the documentation, but I am just beginning, so still have some problems :) But thank you very much for your help!! Really :)